# Get next available date for an out-of-stock, but incoming product

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running an online store that gets all of it's stock info from an external ERP system. I have a few products that are on backorder, and I want to show the next available date on the product page.

I have access to the ERP system database and all incoming shipment delivery dates, deliveries for a single product would look like this:

| product | incoming_date | incoming |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 20210607 | 34 |
| ABC123 | 20210621 | 17 |
| ABC123 | 20210705 | 34 |
| ABC123 | 20210715 | 17 |

I also know that for this spesific product I have 59 units on backorder from customers (number is available in the same database, I have control over this and therefore it's just stored as the variable @Backorder (integer) in the following query). I currently have 0 in stock. This means that the first and second shipment is already sold, and the next available date would be 2021-07-05 (third row).

I've been fiddling with this the last couple of hours, but I am unable to find a good solution.

The closest I have come is this:

```
DECLARE @Product AS VARCHAR(100)='ABC123';
DECLARE @Sold AS INT = 59;

SELECT row, product, incoming_date, incoming, available,

CASE WHEN available < 0 THEN 0 ELSE available-LAG(ABS(available),1) OVER (ORDER BY row) END AS new_available

FROM 
(SELECT row, product, incoming_date, incoming,
    CASE WHEN available < 0 THEN available ELSE incoming-ABS(LAG(available) OVER (ORDER BY row)) END AS available

    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ArDt ASC) AS row, ProdNo AS product, ArDt AS incoming_date, SUM(NoInvoAb) AS incoming,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ArDt ASC) = 1 
        THEN SUM(NoInvoAb)-@Sold ELSE 0 END AS available
        FROM OrderLines WHERE TrTp = 6 AND NoInvoAb != 0 AND ProdNo = @Product GROUP BY ArDt, ProdNo
    ) AS A
) AS B
```

Which results in this:

| row | product | incoming_date | incoming | available | new_available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123 | 20210607 | 34.000000 | -25.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2 | ABC123 | 20210621 | 17.000000 | -8.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 3 | ABC123 | 20210705 | 34.000000 | 34.000000 | 26.000000 |
| 4 | ABC123 | 20210715 | 17.000000 | 17.000000 | -17.000000 |

As you can see, it kinda works, but the fourth and following rows it stops giving correct results. I would have to loop the "new_available" over and over, which is... not desirable.

Complete result shown for debug purposes. In the end I don't need all the information in the table, just the next available date, ie. 2021-07-05 where there are 26 units available.

Are there any better solutions to this problem? Any ideas on a better approach?

PS: Must be solved in the SQL-query itself, calculating it in the webshop is (for now) not an option.

All responses and ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, at the end of the day you just want a cumulative sum corrected by the number of already ordered units.

Your query is confusing. It uses columns not shown in your example. Next time please make sure to post a consistent [example]. To simplify things I will use the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             (product varchar(6),
              incoming_date date,
              incoming integer);

INSERT INTO elbat
            (product,
             incoming_date,
             incoming)
            VALUES
('ABC123', '20210607', 34),
('ABC123', '20210621', 17),
('ABC123', '20210705', 34),
('ABC123', '20210715', 17);
```

To get the number of available items per delivery date, you can use the following query using the `sum()` window function minus the amount already ordered.

```
DECLARE @ordered integer = 59;
DECLARE @product varchar(6) = 'ABC123';

SELECT product,
       incoming_date date,
       CASE 
         WHEN sum(incoming) OVER (ORDER BY incoming_date) - @ordered < 0 THEN
           0
         ELSE 
           sum(incoming) OVER (ORDER BY incoming_date) - @ordered
       END available
       FROM elbat
       WHERE product = @product;
```

If you're only interested in the next day the availability is greater then zero, you can basically put that into a derived table and use `min()` on the day.

```
DECLARE @ordered integer = 59;
DECLARE @product varchar(6) = 'ABC123';

SELECT min(date)
       FROM (SELECT incoming_date date,
                    sum(incoming) OVER (ORDER BY incoming_date) - @ordered available
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE product = @product) x
       WHERE available > 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8513eb052711dd64ab4237fa6e5dd138)

Comment: I can see where that is confusing. I used aliases in the "first" derived query so I could adapt the same query to different ERP's, if that makes sense.