# Get next avail date for an out-of-stock, but incoming product pt 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This question from over a year ago almost answers my question but it falls short just a bit.
[Get next available date for an out-of-stock, but incoming product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67764851/get-next-available-date-for-an-out-of-stock-but-incoming-product)

In the question above, the OP has 59 units on backorder.
They are using that as a simple INT.

So putting my question into the context of the above question,

Let's say I want to know when each sales order might be potentially fulfilled by the next available date.

So that 59 units on backorder might be:

16 units on an order dated 20 April 2021

20 units on an order dated 29 April 2021

8 units on an order dated 2 May 2021

11 units on an order dated 10 May 2021

4 units on an order dated 19 May 2021

Pretty sure thats 59!

Using the age of each order, the first order(s) gets the first available incoming stock until those orders consume all available stock - in which case the next orders yet to be fulfilled will get the next delivery of incoming stock, until they consume that next delivery.

And so on.

I basically need to know the incoming date for each sales order currently waiting for stock.  Based on a date-based priority.

The SQL from the linked question comes so close but I am just having trouble combining that answer with my question.

Comment: I still think it is worthwhile providing a minimal example of what you are looking for. As I understand the question: you want to show order fulfillment dates based on the stock arrival dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE #order_item( order_id int identity, product varchar(6), quantity int )
CREATE TABLE #elbat( product varchar(6), incoming_date date, incoming integer);
INSERT INTO #elbat
VALUES('ABC123', '20210607', 34), ('ABC123', '20210621', 17), ('ABC123', '20210705', 34), ('ABC123', '20210715', 17);
INSERT INTO #order_item
VALUES('ABC123', 8), ('ABC123', 23), ('ABC123', 9), ('ABC123', 45), ('ABC123', 100);


SELECT  orders.seq, orders.product, orders.quantity, MIN( incoming_date )
FROM 
    ( SELECT order_id AS seq, product, quantity, 
                SUM( quantity ) OVER (ORDER BY order_id) AS cumulative_total
            FROM #order_item ) AS back_orders

    LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT product, incoming_date, incoming,
                SUM( incoming ) OVER (ORDER BY incoming_date) AS cumulative_total,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY incoming_date) AS seq
            FROM #elbat ) AS stock
        ON back_orders.product = stock.product AND back_orders.cumulative_total <= stock.cumulative_total
GROUP BY orders.seq, orders.product, orders.quantity
```

Essentially, you want to compute cumulative sums on your order/order_items table and then join that to the cumulative sums of the stock table.

Code is based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67765377/6305294) of the referenced question.